# Square Brackets Within Brackets (was: Twopage Graphics in Headers)

Tags: graphics, header-footer, fancyhdr

How can I scale graphics on alternate pages using fancyhdr from within a template that other corroborators use?

The first listing below is a working example, and the second is the failing example. The only difference is the definition of "\rhead"

texerr.sty (works without scaling):

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[letterpaper, headheight=80px, top=.5in, bottom=.5in, left=1in, right=.5in, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead[\thepage]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.08]{images/logo.eps}}
\chead{Sample Title}
\rhead[\includegraphics{images/logo.eps}]{\thepage}
\cfoot{Jon}
\title{
My Title
}
```

texerr.sty (fails when scaling is included):

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[letterpaper, headheight=80px, top=.5in, bottom=.5in, left=1in, right=.5in, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead[\thepage]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.08]{images/logo.eps}}
\chead{Sample Title}
\rhead[\includegraphics[scale = 0.08]{images/logo.eps}]{\thepage}
\cfoot{Jon}
\title{
My Title
}
```

error on the second example:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
l.9 ...cludegraphics[scale = 0.08]{images/logo.eps}]
                                              {\thepage}
```

Generic implementation .tex file:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{texerr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
Todo: Copyright Page
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is square brackets within square brackets.  This confuses TeX.

Just put the optional argument in additional braces, `[{...}]` like this:

```
\rhead[{\includegraphics[scale = 0.08]{images/logo.eps}}]{\thepage}
```